# Problema con mqttws31.js en broker MQTT montado en Windows

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt

Estoy trabajando con comunicación MQTT para un proyecto IOT. Instalé un broker Mosquitto en Windows y todo funciona ok cuando trabajo entre suscriptores y publicadores en Python o vía línea de comandos entre máquinas de una misma red local. Para el cliente web estoy usando mqttws31.js y para probarlo utilicé un broker mosquitto montado en un servidor Linux externo que funciona perfecto. También funciona cuando en el host del cliente esta configurado con Localhost. No obstante cuando lo configuro con la Ip del mismo localhost servidor, deja de funcionar. Dejo los antecedentes:

- Servidor: mosquitto-1.5.3 ( acepta ws) https://mosquitto.org/download
- Cliente JS : https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/
- mosquitto.conf Contiene la configuración correcta:
- listener 1883
- listener 1884
- protocol mqtt
- istener 2883
- protocol websockets

Inicio con:  mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf

**cliente js**

```
mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(localhost,2883,"clientjs"); // Funciona, pero 
//obviamente no sirve porque al consumirlo, el cliente de otra máquina local 
//dirigirá a su propio localhost.

mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(192.168.1.36,2883,"clientjs"); // No funciona. 
//La ip 192.168.1.36 es la ip de la máquina servidor 
//(es decir es la ip del localhost) que contiene el broker
```

**Error**: *WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.36:2883/mqtt' failed: Error
   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

**Acciones tomadas**

- El servidor mosquitto está habilitado en el firewall de Windows
- El puerto 2883 está habilitado en el firewall de windows y router (Aunque no 
  se si esta bien configurado)

**Conjeturas**

- Si el cliente JS funciona bien utilizando un broker externo, el problema no es del cliente es del servidor.
- Si el cliente js funciona bien utilizando el broker local "Localhost" es por que "esta bien configurado".
- Si el cliente js **no** funciona en el mismo el broker local "Localhost" utilizando la ip... No tengo idea por que puede ser...

**Nota:** Se que todo funcionaría mejor en Linux pero en este caso debemos usar un servidor Windows para el broker.

**Diagrama explicativo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ni idea de sobre lo que estás preguntando, pero `localhost` es **siempre** `127.0.0.1`. `192.168.1.36` será la dirección dentro de tu red local.

Comment: Claro,  pero si  tienes una red local y quieres comunicarte con una máquina vecina no puedes comunicarte a través de 127.0.0.1 debes comunicarte a travez de la dirección que la red local te asigna. en este caso 192.168.1.36

Comment: Ok. Es que me parece que está confuso así. Si lo he entendido bien, tu problema es que no te puedes comunicar con tu Broker desde fuera de tu red local. Y me ha costado varias lecturas entenderlo (si es que lo he entendido)

Comment: Jajaja, gracias por tu interés: Puede que me expliqué mal. Siempre estoy dentro de la red local (no me quiero comunicar desde afuera). No me puedo comunicar con el broker que está en la misma máquina ni desde otra maquina cuando le asigno la ip del servidor local. Pero si me puedo comunicar en ambos casos cuando le asigno una ip de un broker ubicado fuera de la red local. Voy a subir un diagrama para explicarlo mejor.